# The shell script called inside 'Execute Shell' build step fails, but Jenkins build is marked as passed

Tags: shell, jenkins, puppet

I am calling a shell script with some parameters within 'Execute Shell' build step in Jenkins.

```
./shell_1.sh "$Param1" "$Param2" "$Param3"
```

This shell script downloads puppet modules, sets up the directories and then finally calls a puppet script.

```
puppet apply ${WORKSPACE}/scripts/puppet/sample.pp
```

The problem here is that Jenkins console shows the error from the puppet script and then finish with Success status.

Following are the last 3 lines from Jenkins console:

```
06:46:44 [1;31mError: /Stage[main]/Main/Deployit_environment[Environments/Build/Test/UAT/UAT-env]: Could not evaluate: cannot send request to deployit server 404/Not Found:Repository entity [Infrastructure/Build/Test/UAT/server_123/test-sample-service] not found[0m
06:46:44 [mNotice: Applied catalog in 1.82 seconds[0m
06:46:45 Finished: SUCCESS
```

I want the Jenkins job to fail if there is any error in puppet script.

I tried calling shell script with -xe option. But didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen several similar questions recently, did Jenkins screw up? Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using  Jenkins version: 2.73.3

Comment: The problem is likely to be that the shell script you're running in fact *does not* fail, but rather exits with code 0, as one answer already remarks.  I suspect that what you really want to know is why the script does not fail, but until and unless you present relevant details of the script, preferably in the form of a [mcve], we can only speculate about why it behaves as it does.

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins Build step checks if the error code of the script is `0`. If it has another value it will fail the build.

You can use special shell variable called `$?` to get the exit status of the previously executed command. To print `$?` variable use the echo command:

```
echo $?
```

Comment: The error code is '0' only. I think it's showing the exit code for the last line i.e.
`06:46:44 [mNotice: Applied catalog in 1.82 seconds[0m `


The error is in previous line. Any idea how can I stop puppet to execute the 'Applied Catalog' line ?

Comment: just verify that with an additional `echo $?`. Maybe also inside your shell script.